# How to sum two categories within a single column and show the totals to the side of the column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have a list of trailers with a column to the side that says if the trailer is full or a pup trailer. I can't figure out how to make the column total how many of each type of trailer and show the totals of each off to the side.

Comment: By your post it looks like you tried to attach an image - if you did you can post a link to it in the comments and someone will add it for you.

Comment: I did but it's ok. You guys helped. COUNTIF formula does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [countif](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) like this -

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B8,"pup")
```

and

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B8,"full")
```

Just adjust the range to your column and place the formula wherever you'd like the numbers to appear. Also adjust the words "pup" and "full" to match your words and capitalization.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If your question is solved, please click the green checkmark next to the answer that solved it so the question shows up as solved.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this website but i like it already. Very quick response to my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Check the formula called `COUNTIF`, for example something like :

```
COUNTIF(C2:C50,"pup")
```